# Returning IQueryable<T> with async

Tags: c#, iqueryable, mediatr

I'm using MediatR, the `Handle` method in the interface only returns `Task<T>`. As I would like to return `IQueryable<T>` like so:

```
 public class FindProducts : IRequest<IQueryable<Models.Product>>
    {
        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<FindProducts, IQueryable<Models.Product>>
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

            public Handler(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
            {
                _dbContext = dbContext;
            }

            public Task<IQueryable<Models.Product>> Handle(FindProducts request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return _dbContext.Products
                .Select(p => new Models.Product
                {
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Status = new ProductStatus
                    {
                        Id = p.Status.Id,
                        Status = p.Status.Status
                    }
                })
                .AsAsyncEnumerable();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to return `IQueryable<T>` as `async` without `ToListAsync()`?

Comment: are you using ```await```  when calling Handle? That will wait for the task to finish and return the resulting type which is ```IQueryable<Models.Product>>```

Comment: Does the above code compile?

Comment: Does `return Task.FromResult(_dbContext.Products
                .Select(p => new Models.Product
                {
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Status = new ProductStatus
                    {
                        Id = p.Status.Id,
                        Status = p.Status.Status
                    }
                }));` work?

Comment: `.Products.Select(...)` returns an `IQuerable`. Returning an IQuerable shouldn't require any async / Task. But you can call `Task.FromResult`.

Comment: @mjwills The code doesn't compile as it expects to return a Task but this isn't doing so

Comment: Did my suggestion work?

Comment: I feel like Task.FromResult is a bit nasty considering I would have to do this for every command on MediatR, is there no way to make MediatR non async requests?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having async and sync CQRS request and command handlers. Also I would think carefully about letting IQueryable leak back through this sort of abstraction making a guarantee you can write any query against the results... This is a false promise and commonly known as a leaky abstraction. In short I think what you are doing is a little smelly and flawed with Task and IQueryable in general. However this becomes a topic for SoftwareEngineering not Stackoverflow

Comment: `I feel like Task.FromResult is a bit nasty considering I would have to do this for every command on MediatR,` Doesn't seem nasty to me.